# Does xgboost use the TPU for `gpu-hist` (if TPU is available)?

Tags: google-colaboratory, xgboost, tpu, google-cloud-tpu

I am curious if xgboost will use a TPU in google colab if such is available? It certainly makes very good use of the GPU...

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your question. TPU's are typically great at Neural Network based models. I have not heard of a way to do tree-based computations on TPUs, and I highly doubt that TPUs would be performant at that today as things stand.

Comment: Well, the GPU enabled xgboost is FAR faster than the CPU version, so one must ask what features of the GPU it uses... Google also has a treeboost estimator  (though it does not seem to be competitive with xgboost and friends).

Comment: Gpus are generally good w/ tasks that can be run in parallel, and tree construction is such a task (finding splits accross various columns is parallelizable). TPUs on the other hand are super fast w/ matrix type operations like matmul, convolutions, etc. I haven't used treeboost so cannot comment on that.